# Next deploy via Vercel: found pages without a React Component as default export in

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel

When I deploy my Nextjs app I get a buid err. Vercel doesn`t see nested pages. How can I override it, maybe it is posible in vercel.json?

*Building logs*
[image: building logs]

*Project structure*

[image: project structure]

I tried this, but it`s breaks everything

```
module.exports = {
    pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try moving your components outside `pages` folder as [Next.js has a file-system based router built on the concept of pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction).

Hope you should be using `export default` instead of `export` inside `index.tsx` for exporting your component.